# NSTask in playground

Tags: macos, swift, nstask, swift-playground

I'm wondering if NSTask is not available in playgrounds.
This does not compile

```
import Foundation
let task = NSTask()
```

Does anyone know if that's not (yet) possible or am I missing something?

**Update**
It's possible to create iOS or OS X playgrounds. One can also change the chosen platform after the initial creation of the playground: Xcode > View > Utilities > Show File Inspector **(cmd+opt+1)** -> There is a drop down menu for the platform.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Aren't playgrounds iOS only? `NSTask` isn't available there.

Comment: Works for me in both 6.1.1 and 6.2 beta 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried it with an OS X playground (which do exist, past me) and it compiled without issues.

```
import Foundation
let task = NSTask()
```

Outputs `NSConcreteTask`, and `println()` on the task gives `<NSConcreteTask: 0x7fe4f1f27360>`. Make sure it is an OS X playground though, as iOS does not include `NSTask`

Comment: Thank you, I really created an iOS Playground. Solved!